# Explain Singleton class in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does your Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like)

Can anyone explain what is singleton in objective c with an example.

Answer (score 0):

For the most comprehensive answer on singletons in Objective C look here:
[What should my Objective-C singleton look like?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like)

It has all been answered before and with several examples.